# Is saveAll method of SpringData Jpa atomic?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For example if I have a products repository, and I use the `saveAll(products)`, will it be atomic? Or for it to be atomic I need to enable batch? Like in this guide? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts, if you have any documentation regarding my question feel free to post.

In my case I am using a MySql database and also extending from JpaRepository<>

Comment: If you mean with atomic that all entities will be saved in one transaction and committed at the end in case of success. And all changes rolled back at the end in case of error. The answer is yes, saveAll works like this. Calling in a batch is another thing and can be activated in addition. To increase the speed.

Comment: @Mar-Z yes that is what I ment, thank you, so no need to activate batch for atomicity, I prefer then to let things as they are

Comment: @Mar-Z Just wondering if you could provide any documentation that validates this? Tried to find it but no luck

Comment: Just the source code. You can see the @Transactional is used for saveAll https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/d2b244b4ea10c70e86f1cc8c109293531123c4b0/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L693